# setting tags on Imageviews in your adapter and memorizing these

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, adapter

Hello stackoverflow community,

suppose i have a function setTags() which gives the imageviews of your adapter tags like in this code below:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Bitmap> crops;
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> crops) {
    mContext = c;
    this.crops = crops;
    setTags();
}

public int getCount() {
    return crops.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(crops.get(position));
    return imageView;
}
public void setTags(){
    for(int i = 0; i<getCount();i++){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
        img.setImageBitmap(crops.get(i));
        img.setTag(i);
        img = null;         
    }
}
```

}

Does my class where i make the gridview import these tags? So for example when i'm in the Onclicklistener of my gridview. And i click on the image whose tag is supposed to be 0, wil i get the tag if i do:

img = (ImageView) view;
img.getTag();

or are the tags forgotten?

tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tags will not stay, you are setting them for "empty" newly created `ImageView`s (then null), not `ImageView`s in `getView`...

also

```
public Object getItem(int position) { //or even public Bitmap getItem(...
    return crops.get(i);
}
```

and you might set tag for bitmaps in your `setTags()` method, then inside `getView` `imageView.setTag(getItem().getTag());` but as I see you are setting simply `position` as a tag so you might strictly `imageView.setTag(position);`

so inside `getView`

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));
imageView.setTag(position);
```

note that when you are using `setOnItemClickListener` you will get plain position (as below) inside callback method (or maybe you need them for other purposes...)

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, 
        int position, long id) {

}
```